# Android uses wrong string ressource

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?
I made a editor for my in game Shared Preferences as a Activity. There is a list with all values of one Shared Preferences. But when i write for a `textView` called `value_theme`:

`value_theme.setText(R.string.editor_div_value + settings_theme);`

Android uses an other string resource from an other activity.

When i write

`value_theme.setText(R.string.editor_div_value + "" + settings_theme);`

the app sets the TextView text to: 21312309366. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: When i use value_theme.setText("current value. " + settings_theme); everything works fine, but i want to develop for more than one language.

Comment: settings_theme is the value from the Shared Preference

Comment: `R.string.editor_div_value` is just a number, which is like an index to the string value. You need to acquire the string value, not just reference the index. See @Bob answer for an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
value_theme.setText(context.getString(R.string.editor_div_value) + "" + settings_theme);
```

Since you are appending the string, you are mistakenly using the wrong `setText` method which accepts a `CharSequence` and sets to the `TextView` as it is.

Or another way is to do String formatting.

```
<string name="editor_div_value">Your String value %1$s</string>
```

To get the String in Java code:

```
value_theme.setText(context.getString(R.string.editor_div_value, settings_theme));
```

Comment: do you mean getApplicationContext() with context?

Comment: You can pass any context. Activity or application context.